# Overlap of labels in jsplumb

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsplumb

Is there a way to avoid overlapping labels using jsplumb? Sometimes I have quite a few plumbing lines and the label text is awfully close to each other. I want to implement some styling on the elements to make them more readable, but this makes it even worse.

Is there a way to spread them out or add margins somehow so they don't clash like this?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can add margins

```
overlays: [
                                        ["Label", {
                                            location: [0,0],
                                            cssClass: "foo",
                                            label: 'Drop',                                                
                                        }],
                                        ["Label", {
                                            location: [0.5, 1.5],
                                            label: "Drag",
                                            cssClass: "endpointSourceLabel"
                                        }]
                                    ]
```

CSS

```
.foo{
 margin : 10px;
}
.endpointSourceLabel{
 padding : 5px 10px;
 margin : 5px 3px;
}
```

Comment: That's just moving the label along the line isn't it? Often times this is a problem when I have 5 or more connections, and the labels are too long to all fit next to each other like that. The only way they would fit is on top of each other.

Comment: yes, it's just moving along the line. Having the labels near to the source or target (acc. to your requirement) should lessen the chances of label overlap. My answer was particularly about how to position them & add margins. You can use whatever values suiting your application & offers less probability of overlap.